# Lebesgue Integral and Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

So far I have learned the definition of Lebesgue integration, and say we do Lebesgue integration of measurable function $f$ in the measure space $(X,M,\mu)$. I notice that $\mu$ does not have to be the Lebesgue measure $m$. Is that correct? In other words, is it ok to understand Lebesgue integration as a general technique and Lebesgue measure as just one tool that we can use for that technique, but the Lebesgue measure is not the only one we can use?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: An example: Integrals w.r.t [counting measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_measure) are sums (and series). The theorems derived for general integrals, like the [Tonelli-Fubini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) can therefore be used for series.